# Show name property of associated external content type in display/edit form

Tags: lookup-column, external-content-type, edit-form

I have an external list. The underlying external content type has an association to another external content type. The content types are built in sharepoint designer.

When I edit the item - the associated type is shown as ID. How can I set this field to display a certain property? For e.g. instead of customer ID display the customer name in the display/edit form.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be very simple. I just dint know about it.

I found the answer in this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx#section11

1. In the Sharepoint designer - select the External Content Type.
2. On the ribbon, click Summary View.
3. In the Fields section, under Field Name, select a field.
4. On the ribbon, click Set as Title.